# Getting datamapper to ignore 'type' when querying the database

Tags: ruby, datamapper, single-table-inheritance

I've got a single table inheritance structure in my application whereby Admins and Mods extends a User class. The table uses a discriminator value so each record has a type of either "admin" or "mod"

When it comes to finding a user (on login) I'd like to write the following:

```
current_user = User.find(params[:email => email])
```

However, this creates SQL which includes

```
SELECT ...... WHERE ("type" IN ('User') AND .....
```

This means that the record cannot be found. However if I type

```
current_user = Admin.find(params[:email => email])
```

I get the user (if they are an admin).

I've also tried the following to no avail since the 'type' IN ('User') is still created:

```
current_user = User.first(:email => email, :type => [Admin, Mod])
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
current_user = User.first(:email => email, :type => ['Admin', 'Mod'])
```

Comment: Afraid not. The resulting sql looks something like: 

SELECT .....FROM "users" WHERE ("type" IN ('User') AND "type" IN ('Admin', 'Mod') AND "email" = .......